# How to make C application with unixodbc on Ubuntu

Tags: unixodbc

I just want to run a test program using ODBC calls on Ubuntu but can't find any information on what includes to use or how to link.  Is there a sample makefile? I've used ODBC on Windows with no problem.

Also unixodbc documentation refers to ODBCConfig but this doesn't seem to be on my system.

There are also references to the package unixodbc-gui-qt but apt-get can't find it.

Comment: Question: have you installed unixODBC on your system? Please check using the following command `dpkg-query -l | grep -i odbc`

Comment: Yes, odbcunix and odbcunix-dev are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Evans provide the information for compile / linking
cc -I/dir -Ldir xxx.c -Ldir -lodbc -lodbcinst

It appears that ODBCConfig no longer exists but 
zxMarce posted this information:
The hard way I learnt that "ODBCConfig" was replaced by
"ODBCCreateDataSourceQ4" (wizard-like) and "ODBCManageDataSourcesQ4".
Remember to prefix any of those with "sudo" if you will create/edit any
ODBC system setting

Unfortunately, the DB2 ODBC driver didn't seem to install itself such that those tools could find it so hopefully manually editing the odbc configuration files will work.